# Firebase function looping after error over and over?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

An issue has showed up with my firebase function. It was working perfect until 3 weeks ago, and I cannot seem to find a solution, it's a 1st gen function. It keeps looping to the beginning of the function all the time when this error shows: response size was too large. please consider reducing response size.

The function does what it supposed to do, however it loops and restart sending the push messages again. I have tried adding return false and return true to check if it stops at the end, but it keeps coming back.

```
exports.setPushMessageAll = functions.database.ref("postslive/{userId}/{postId}").onCreate((change, context) => {let newdata = change.val();let devices = [];let return_val = null;let return_valmeio = null;let posterid = change.val().userid;let visitor = change.val().usertype;let needs_list = ["Tiroteio", "Arrastão", "Operação Policial", "Manifestação", "Alagamento", "Incêndio", "Disparos Ouvidos", "Carros voltando na Contramao", "Perseguição Policial", "Utilidade Pública e Outros", "Promocional OTT", "Roubo de carga", "Toque de recolher"];let data = newdata.eventname;let tiponeed = change.val().need;console.log("Membro tipo", change.val().usertype);// console.log("tipo", needs_list);// console.log("dados tipo", tiponeed);// console.log("dados completo", newdata);

let myTime = new Date();const cutoff = 1672673662000;// let diacompleto = dia+"/"+month+"/"+Yearlet diacompleto = myTime.toLocaleString("pt-BR");


if (tiponeed !== "9") {console.log("tipo de alerta final", tiponeed);console.log("bairro 1", newdata.location.bairro);if (newdata.location.bairro !== "" && (newdata.location.bairro !== undefined)) {console.log("bairro 2", newdata.location.bairro);// return admin.database().ref("users").orderByChild("isvisitor").equalTo("0").once("value", usrparentsnapshot => {return admin.database(Usuarios_dev).ref("users").orderByChild("latestlogintime").startAt(cutoff).once("value", (usrparentsnapshot) => {// return admin.database(Usuarios_dev).ref("users").orderByChild("isvisitor").equalTo("0").startAt(cutoff).once("value", (usrparentsnapshot) => {console.log("bairro loop", newdata.location.bairro);console.log("bairro state", newdata.location.state);

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: needs_list[parseInt(newdata.need)],
        body: "Local: " + newdata.location.bairro + newdata.location.county + " " + newdata.location.municipio,
        image: "ic_stat_icon_material",
      //    sound: "default"
      },
    };

    usrparentsnapshot.forEach((usersnapshot) => {
    //  console.log("users snap");
      if (usersnapshot.hasChild("settings") === true && (usersnapshot.hasChild("token") === true) && (usersnapshot.hasChild("currentlocation") === true)) {
        if (usersnapshot.val().settings.isNotification === true) {
          let radlat1 = Math.PI * usersnapshot.val().currentlocation.lat/180;
          let radlat2 = Math.PI * newdata.location.lat/180;
          let theta = usersnapshot.val().currentlocation.long - newdata.location.lng;
          let radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
          let dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
          if (dist > 1) {
            dist = 1;
          }
          dist = Math.acos(dist);
          dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
          dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
          dist = dist * 1.609344;

          if (dist <= usersnapshot.val().settings.notiradius) {
            if (usersnapshot.val().token && (usersnapshot.val().token !== "") && (usersnapshot.val().token !== undefined)) {
              devices.push(usersnapshot.val().token);
            }

            if (devices.length > 900) {
              admin.messaging().sendToDevice(devices, payload);
              //  return return_valmeio; console.log("Maior que 500 Membro, enviado", devices.length);
              devices = [];
              console.log("tamanho depois Membro", devices.length);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    console.log("tamanho antes if Membro", devices.length);
    //    console.log("notificacao",payload)return;
    if (devices.length > 0) {
      admin.messaging().sendToDevice(devices, payload);
      console.log("tamanho final Membro", devices.length);
      devices = [];
    }
    console.log("Final Membro", devices.length);
    if (devices.length === 0) {
      console.log("terminou");
      devices = [];
    }
  });
}
console.log("final 0");

}console.log("cheguei no retorno");return true;});
```